# Wordpress query to show only posts where content is not empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a query to show only 1 custom post type randomly on my home page. I'm trying to filter out the posts where the content is empty so as to not show those posts in the loop. Is it possible to set the query to only show post that "post_content" is not empty? I've tried "meta_query" with no luck. [As covered here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10881/how-can-i-show-posts-only-if-meta-value-is-not-empty#11090)

I have also played around with other things, like trying to get the next post in the loop if the content is empty, but can't find a way to do that either.

Here is something I was trying to get the next post, if content is empty. But I don't think "get_next_post();" works that way.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'custom',
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    ) );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

if($post->post_content=="") {
get_next_post();
} else {
the_title();
the_content();
};
endwhile;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually I tried that too, but it didn't seem to work correctly. It started adding other post types, and pages to my query output.

Comment: I just tried it myself and it works fine. Are you sure you don't have collisions elsewhere?

Comment: Bummer. I must have a collision elsewhere because I get everything returned. Pages, Posts, even Revisions content. In fact, everything except my custom post type. But never empty...ha

Answer (score 2):

Something basic like this should work for you. Trimming the post content first ensures that you're not inadvertently including posts with nothing but whitespace.

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    if(trim($post->post_content) !== "") {
        the_title();
        the_content();
    };
endwhile;
```

Comment: This should work but the duplicate seems like it's filtering using the database (so more efficient, no?)

Comment: Could be, but it's a micro-optimization in my opinion. I'd sooner have something more readable, even if it means sacrificing a few clock cycles.

Comment: I dunno about micro-optimization... if he's trying to only display, say, 8 posts and 3 are technically blank, his method will only display 5 but the other answer's method will actually show 8.

Comment: Another issue is that given the number of custom post types out there, there might be an instance where a certain resource is being leveraged strictly from its metadata and should not be excluded at the query level. Excluding posts like that makes too many assumptions, and really should be filtered at the templating level. But this is all opinion, and no answer should be taken as a "one size fits all" solution.

Comment: I've never really used WP (and the more I see of it, the less I want to;) You're right that there's no "one size fits all" answer.

Comment: You're right about that much. The codebase is a maintenance nightmare. I do it only when clients specifically request it. Otherwise, I suggest Laravel, Silex, or Slim. All wonderful.

Comment: That looked perfect to me, nice and simple. But didn't work. I'm still seeing posts with empty content.